# How to iterate through a multidimensional JSON array?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

My code is:

```
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p ng-repeat="maintGroup in maintGroups"> Some text in the modal and {{ maintGroup.serviceGroup.services[$index].description.custDescription }} </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
```

maintGroup refers to the following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "groupId":"MSG1",
    "mileage":150000,
    "serviceGroup":{
      "description":"BRAKES",
      "opCode":"BRK",
      "serviceGroupId":"SG1",
      "serviceType":"BRAKES",
      "services":[
        {
          "description":{
            "custDescription":"Replace right front brake motor",
            "descriptionId":"D1"
          },
          "image":{
            "imageId":"IMG1"
          },
          "serviceId":"S1"
        }
```

I'm struggling to find a way to loop through the customer descriptions. I know the paths should be: maintGroup.serviceGroup.services[0].description.custDescription where 0 should be i. I just don't know how to get it to work. $index only works for index 0, but doesn't loop for the rest of ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to want to nest another repeat inside your `ng-repeat="maintGroup in maintGroups"`

Try adding an element with `ng-repeat='service in maintGroup.serviceGroup.services'`, and then somewhere inside of that you can call `{{ service.description.customerDescription }}`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I didn't know I could nest another ng-repeat. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Happy to help. Have fun